# Pass parameter to anonymous method?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-methods

I have the following method :

```
while (TryCount < 2)
{
    Lock.Try<object>(inCommandObj.Connection, _timeout, delegate(DataSet ds)
    {
        dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(inCommandObj);
        returningObj = dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        done = true;
        return returningObj;
    });

    if (done)
        break;

    inCommandObj.Cancel();
}
```

You can see that Im trying to pass a DataSet in to this anonymous method but it does not like it? How can I make this possible?

Bestregards

Edit 1 : Exception message now is : Delegate 'System.Func' does not take 1 arguments

Edit 2 : In this case I need to fill a existing dataset with the dataAdapter.Fill method. This have to be done using a lock(with timout) becouse there will be alot of threads running this method. If the lock times out I need to cancel the current MySQL command that have frezzed and then try to send a new command(1 time).

Edit 3 : This is how the lock Class looks like :

```
public static class Lock
    {
        public static T Try<T>(object objLock, int timeout, Func<T> f)
        {
            if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(objLock, timeout))
            {
                try
                {
                    return f.Invoke();
                }
                finally
                {
                    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(objLock);
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }

        public static void Try(object objLock, int timeout, Action f)
        {
            if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(objLock, timeout))
            {
                try
                {
                    f.Invoke();
                }
                finally
                {
                    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(objLock);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you know "it doesn't like it"?

Comment: "it does not like it" is a rather poor description of the problem. What happens? What is the error message?

Comment: and what are you trying to do? your code hurt my eyes. perhaps, if you write what you want to do , someone can give you a better solution.

Comment: Why are you passing `ds` at all if you're just immediately reassigning it?

Comment: What is `TryCount` and why isn't this an infinite loop?

Comment: @Madbreaks look at Edit 1.

Comment: Add a break point to each Lock method. Which one is being called when you have no parameter in the delegate? The Action one right? So when you add a parameter you are trying to get the Func<T> to run. However, you defined T as object, not Dataset. Beyond that, you don't have any mechanism to acutally pass the needed argument to the lock method.

Comment: @JonB Dataset is not reassigned, it is filled.

Comment: @asawyer, I dont want to try more then 2 times and then giveup and see Edit 3.

Comment: @asawyer it is not possible to run the application att all, the syntax is not correct

Comment: You still didnt write what you are trying to do, whatever your are trying with lock and monitors are very dangerous.

Comment: @DarthVader, The problem is that when running diffrent operations lile ExecuteScaler and so on to the MySQL database it will sometime freez and I need to cancel the command from another thread else it will never let go. Thats why I need to use the loop. The ODBCConnection have to be withou lock(If I got it right?) when using multiple threads at the same time. I am opening and closing only once and not for every call or thread. All threads will use the same ODBCConnection to avoid opening alot of connections.

Comment: @Ivy `ds = new DataSet();` -- this assigns a new instance of a `DataSet` to `ds`.

Comment: ok but why are trying to do this yourself, there are frameworks you can use easily, take nhibernate or EF. you will probably leave a bug with this code. just saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
public static T Try<T>(object objLock, int timeout, Func<T> f)
```

`Func<T>` is looking for a function that takes no parameters and returns a `T`. You're sending it a delegate that takes a `DataSet` and returns an object.

Since you're creating a new `DataSet` in your delegate anyway, just drop the `DataSet ds` from the delegate and you should be all set.

In fact, you can simplify this to:

```
Lock.Try<object>(inCommandObj.Connection, _timeout, () =>
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(inCommandObj);
    returningObj = dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    done = true;
    return returningObj;
});
```

If that doesn't do what you intended, then you need to refactor `Try` to take a different `Func` argument, or consider a totally different solution.

Comment: How would this look like If I was to take DataSet as a inparameter?

Comment: @Ivy - change the declaration to `public static T Try<T>(object objLock, int timeout, Func<T, DataSet> f)`.